# OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am having a simple code which has an image called "try.png" and I want to convert it from Image to Text using pytesseract but I am having some issues with the code.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe'
img = cv2.imread('try.png')
img= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

But it's giving me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user 1/PycharmProjects/JARVIS/try.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
  File "C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 356, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 359, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 270, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 241, in run_tesseract
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 238, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\user 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea on how to over come this error

Comment: Have you tried launching the code with admin rights?

Comment: Yes,but still got the same error

Comment: Try changing the tesseract executable to run as admin: `Right Click tesseract.exe -> Properties -> Compability -> Check Run this program as an administrator -> OK` . Also, how did you attempt to run the code with admin rights?

Comment: @K41F4r Wait IS it 'tesseract.exe' i wrote my path as 'tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe' i just downloaded this from the website and put this as the path. but I don't have tesseract.exe I have 'tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe' only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe` sounds like a setup exe and not the tesseract itself. Check if you have actually installed tesseract and if not launch the exe to install.

For Windows download the latest version from here:
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

If you still get `OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation` try changing the tesseract executable to run as admin: `Right Click tesseract.exe -> Properties -> Compability -> Check Run this program as an administrator -> OK` .

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yes this solved my problem.Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have not installed tesseract on your system.  Run `tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe` to install it and make a note of the location where it is installed (`$tesseractLocation`)
If getting the same error while installing, try running it with admin access.
And Replace

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe'
```

with

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'$tesseractLocation'
```

This will resolve the issue. In the script, you have to mention the installation directory and not the setup file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yes this solved my problem.Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try Uncheck "Run this program as an administrator" 
TRY: 
`Right Click tesseract.exe -> Properties -> Compability -> Uncheck Run this program as an administrator -> apply`.

Comment: for me when i ran the program as administrator, it worked fine